# URL rewrite and redirection address error

Tags: php, iis-7

I have this rewrite rule in IIS,

```
                <match url="^survey/([0-9]+)" />
                <action type="Rewrite" url="survey.php?id={R:1}" />
```

works great and passes the id to the procedure within. When we have an unassigned id, the procedure redirects the user to a thank you page on the root folder. When I enter the unassigned id for e.g. "..survey?id=20", it redirects to "..thankyou.php". But when I enter "..survey/20", it redirects to "..survey/thankyou.php", resulting in a 'page not found error'.

How do I rewrite the rule so it redirects correctly to '..thankyou.php'.

Thank you and advance
Richard

Comment: Check what happens under the hood, http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules

Comment: Did you get page not found  event when you set action type to redirect and uncheck append query string?

Comment: Jokies, not sure what you are asking me to do, sorry

Comment: Lex Li, thanks will look into it

Comment: Since you are not posting a complete rewrite rule. I suggest to try to change rewrite action to"redirect" and check whether it is redirecting to the correct URL.

Comment: Dear Jokies, many thanks for following-up. I managed to solve the issue. i set the redirect to "../thankyou".